# How to associate a label with a group of radio buttons?

Tags: html

I was shown that in general, there are two ways of labeling `radio` buttons:

Method #1:

```
<label>Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="m"></label>
<label>Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="f"></label>
```

Method #2 (using `for`):

```
<label for="id_male">Male</label>
<input type="radio" id="id_male" name="gender" value="m">
<label for="id_female">Female</label>
<input type="radio" id="id_female" name="gender" value="f">
```

But what if there is a need to associate a group of `radio` buttons with a `label`?

i.e:

```
<label>What is your gender?
    <label>Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="m"></label>
    <label>Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="f"></label>
</label>
```

The questions are:

1. Is the way used to associate the "What is your gender?" `label` above correct?
2. Is there a way to associate "What is your gender?" that corresponds to Method #2 (i.e. using `for`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use method #2 like this:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>What's your gender?</legend>
      <label for="id_male">Male</label>
      <input type="radio" id="id_male" name="gender" value="m">
      <label for="id_female">Female</label>
      <input type="radio" id="id_female" name="gender" value="f">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

See more about [fieldset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is using **fieldset/legend** combination:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Gender</legend> 
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0dg362wq/)

Comment: Missing the <label> tags for the inputs.